# The popular model item passed into the dictis of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[X] but this dictionary requires a model item of type X

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

So yeah I have investigated and read a lot of responses here but they all have mismatch with data types.. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

```
    public class RestaurantBranchModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string telephone { get; set; }

    public int master_restaurant_id { get; set; }

    //public RestaurantModel master_restaurant { get; set; }

    public int address_id { get; set; }

    //public AddressModel address { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 RestaurantBranchRepository RestaurantBranchRepository = new RestaurantBranchRepository();
    IEnumerable<RestaurantBranchModel> Branches;

    // GET: RestaurantBranch
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Branches = RestaurantBranchRepository.GetBranches();
        return View(Branches); //I've also tried adding .ToList()
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<OrdenarBackEnd.Models.RestaurantBranchModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_XenonLayoutPage.cshtml";}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.telephone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.master_restaurant_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address_id)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telephone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.master_restaurant_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

@section BottomScripts{}
```

**//END OF CODE**

So.. I have a the model. I pass a collection of items in the View, the View is under the LIST template for mvc, and it says i am passing a generic list but it needs a single object ? what gives??..

This is the error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OrdenarBackEnd.Models.RestaurantBranchModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'OrdenarBackEnd.Models.UserModel'.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: What model type does `_XenonLayoutPage.cshtml` take?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
```

To

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().name)
```

Basically it needs a single object and you are passing in a list.

Comment: Had that been the problem, he would get a compiler error.